# Insert record if not exists in table failing in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, actions, date, comments, type, url, rating)
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'b7d54d99bf11', 'Information Exchanged', '1430463600', '', 'routine', 'http://example.com', '') AS tmp
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT url FROM table WHERE url = 'http://example.com')
```

I get a SQL Error that says `Duplicate column name: ''` because there is no `rating` or `comments` passed in for some records.

How can I avoid the error? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to include alias for your columns

```
INSERT INTO table (id, actions, date, comments, type, url, rating)
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'b7d54d99bf11' as id, 
                        'Information Exchanged' as actions, 
                        '1430463600' as date, 
                        '' as comments, 
                        'routine' as type, 
                        'http://example.com' as url, 
                        '' as rating) AS tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery that complicated at all:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, actions, date, comments, type, url, rating)
    SELECT 'b7d54d99bf11', 'Information Exchanged', '1430463600', '', 'routine', 'http://example.com', ''
    FROM (SELECT 1 as x) t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT url FROM table WHERE url = 'http://example.com');
```

However, a better method is to let the *database* do the check.  Create a unique constraint/index and then phrase the `insert` to ignore the update when there are duplicates:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_table_url unique(url);

insert into table (id, actions, date, comments, type, url, rating)
    select 'b7d54d99bf11', 'Information Exchanged', '1430463600', '', 'routine', 'http://example.com', ''
    on duplicate key update url = values(url);
```

This has the advantage that the database will ensure uniqueness for all inserts and updates -- and the code that does the database changes does not have to check each time.